# How to Print 2 Datagridview (Bound) in a Single Page in VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net, printing

I have a form which have 2 `Datagridview` Bound with .mdb file. I want to print these datagridview in a page. Is it possible to display both `Datagridview` in a Page?

I am using `DGVPrinter` for Using these 1 `Datagridview` printer. Please help.